# Determine if a record "is new" in the pre save callback

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Is there a way to find out if a record "is new" (has not been save yet) in the pre save callback of mongoose model schema?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Yes, there's an [`isNew`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-isNew) boolean property on a model instance that indicates that.  Access it as `this.isNew` from your pre save middleware.

Comment: Is there a similar indicator for `pre('update'`. I use `UserModel.update(filter, newUser, {upsert:true, new:true}, (err, user) ->`and would like to know if it is a new doc or if it modified an existing one.

Answer (score 37):

```
var MySchema = new Schema({...});

MySchema.pre('save', function(next) {
    if (this.isNew) {
        // Hooray !
    }
    next();
});
```