# mongoose schema check if model instance is saved for the first time

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have 3 schemas, 2 of which have a `.pre('save')` hook to push its `_id` into the previous one's. You can take the example of a forum with topics, questions and comments

```
var topicSchema = new Schema({
  arr: {type:[Schema.ObjectId], ref:'Question'},
});
var Topic = new mongoose.model('Topic', topicSchema);

var questionSchema = new Schema({
  targetId: {type:Schema.ObjectId, ref:'Topic', required:true},
  arr: {type:[Schema.ObjectId], ref:'Comment'},
});
var Question = new mongoose.model('Question', questionSchema);

var commentSchema = new Schema({
  targetId: {type:Schema.ObjectId, ref:'Question', required:true},
});
var Comment = new mongoose.model('Comment', commentSchema);
```

Now for the above schema I want: When I save a question I want to automatically push the question's `_id` to its respective `Topic.arr` and when I save a comment to auto push its it to its respective `Question.arr`

I've tried solving this using `.pre('save')` hooks as follows:

```
function addPreSave (schema, idProperty, containerProperty) {
  var modelName = schema.paths[idProperty].options.ref;
  var model = mongoose.models[modelName];

  schema.pre('save', function (next) {
    model.findById(this[idProperty], function (err, doc) {
      doc[containerProperty].push(this._id);
      doc.save(next);
    }.bind(this));
  });
}

addPreSave(questionSchema, 'targetId', 'arr');
addPreSave(commentSchema, 'targetId', 'arr');
```

All that the above function does (and the 2 calls to it) is to add a `.pre('save')` hook to each of the 2 schemas to add their `_id` in their respective parent.

---

**THE ISSUE:** The problem is that now, every time I save a comment, it pushes its id to the topic, but I only actually want to do this the very first time only. So in the above example if you create a topic, then a question for it and then a comment for the question, the `Topic.arr` will have 2 ids in it (twice the question's `_id`) as it saves once for the question and a second time it's triggered by the comment's call to save the question

Does anyone know a way around this, or more specifically if you know how to figure out in the pre-save hook if this is a first-time save or not?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Determine if a record "is new" in the pre save callback](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12092772/determine-if-a-record-is-new-in-the-pre-save-callback)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

So it turns out that you can find the answer to anything if you are willing to go on the *second page of Google!*

There is a property defined for every document called **isNew** which does what you might imagine. So just adding a `if (!this.isNew) return next()` in the method fixes the issue.

Comment: I was going to complain about the first sentence in your answer thinking it's a bit rude to reply to someone like that and then realized it's your own question haha, cheers! thanks!

Comment: There is supposed to be an `init` hook you can add to your models but it looks like that feature is broken :/ https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/2363